# how to explore a very big variable in python?

Tags: python

I have a problem, I have a python script which loads a very very big variable, lets call it `foo`. Now I want to explore the structure of foo so I write the following code:

```
print foo
```

but the problem is, when I execute this, my IDLE gets blocked and I see any output. I think its because `foo` is to big. Is there any function or s.th. equal to explore a variable?

Comment: Do you mean something like `dir()`? If it's a huge string or list you can try `foo[:10]` or something similar.

Comment: print to a file maybe?

Comment: good idea, plz post this as a answer

Comment: What kind of data structure is it? Enter `type(foo)` and what does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dump the `repr` of `foo` to a text file with something like...

```
open('foo.txt', 'w').write(repr(foo))
```